# How to execute Jmeter test case from command line that is integrated with Robot framework

Tags: jmeter, robotframework

I have installed Jmeter library for robot framework but unable to execute test case through command line.

How to execute Jmeter test case from command line that is integrated with Robot framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run jmeter testcases using the keyword "run jmeter" with 3 arguments. Example is shown below

```
*** Testcases ***
TestCase1
    Execute Jmeter script

*** Keywords ***
Execute Jmeter script
   | run jmeter | D:/apache-jmeter-2.12/bin/jmeter.bat | D:/Tests/Test1Thread1Loop.jmx | ${logPath} |
```

In command prompt, execute the command(from project path )as below:

```
 robot TestCase1.txt
```

Comment: Thanks very much Rakesh !

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu use jmeter.sh instead of jmeter.bat